# How to apply multiple .filter() methods along with a .map() method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filter, mapping

I need to filter hotels by multiple conditions: stars (multiple choice), type (multiple choice), price(range with two ends), country (one of the list). I tried to do that like that:

```
document.getElementById("app").innerHTML =`${hotels.filter(star => star.stars === 4).filter(type => type.type === "hostel").map(hotelTemplate)}`
```

But I found out that I can apply only one method `filter` along with the `map`. Does somebody know if there is a way to apply multiple `filter` methods and then `map` them?

Attaching the full code if you need more details:

```
async function filters(){
    const requestUrl = "js/hotels.json";
    const response = await fetch(requestUrl);
    const data = await response.json();
    const hotels = Object.values(data.hotels);

const hotelTemplate = (hotel) => {
        return `
        <div class="result">
        <img class="result__img" src="images/hotel2.png" alt="${hotel.name}">
        <div class="result__description">
            <p class="result__address">${hotel.address}</p>
            <h3 class="result__name">${hotel.name}</h3>
            <div class="result__details">
                <div class="rating">
                    <div class="rating__stars">${hotel.stars}</div>
                    <p class="rating__words"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="result__type">${hotel.type}</div>
            </div>
            <p class="result__info">${hotel.description}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="result__cta">
        <div class="review">
            <div class="review__head">
                <div class="review__rating">
                    <img class="review__star" src="images/star.svg" alt="${hotel.name}">
                    <p class="review__rate">${hotel.rating}</p>
                </div>
                <p class="review__estimate">Good</p>
                <p class="review__amount"><span class="review__number">${hotel.reviews_amount}</span> reviews</p>
            </div>
            <div class="review__body">
                <p class="review__text">"${hotel.last_review}"</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="order">
            <div class="order__price">
                <p class="order__offer">от <span class="order__amount">${eurFormatter.format(parseInt(hotel.min_price))}</span></p>
            </div>
            <button class="order__book">
                Book now
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
        `;
    }
document.getElementById("app").innerHTML =`${hotels.filter(star => star.stars === 4).map(hotelTemplate)}`
```

Comment: Seems like your code would work. Chaining filters into maps should be fine

Comment: @Kinglish, hello! Thank you for your reply!
Sometimes it does work, but when I need to chain the stars. Let's say the user chose to view the hotels with 3, 4 and 5 stars.
So if I do something like that: 
`document.getElementById("app").innerHTML =${hotels.filter(star => star.stars === 5).filter(star => star.stars === 5).map(hotelTemplate)}`

The code doesn't execute correctly, it doesn't return any error either :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey everyone who reads this message!
I have found the solution here:

**https://gist.github.com/jherax/f11d669ba286f21b7a2dcff69621eb72**

It's highly likely that you will find it there too if you are brought here by the same question as above.